# sql server select rows that have 1 value in ALL columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I want to find out if certain columns all contain the word `Compliant'

the columns are all varchar.

this query selects any row that has `Compliant` in any of the columns.

```
SELECT  curb_reveal_check,
    ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check FROM table    
where 'Compliant' in(ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check)
```

but I need them all to contain `Compliant`

I tried substituting all for in but I got this error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'all'.
```

Comment: ALL doesn't work like that; it requires the thing inside the brackets return a single column of multiple rows and while there is an IN() that works the same i.e. `WHERE some_id IN (SELECT other_id FROM othertable)` that IN is perhaps best thought of as a different IN to the one that works like `IN(list,of,hardcoded,values)` - there isn't a `ALL(hardcoded,list,of,values)`, you'd have to do some tricks to pivot your row into a column.. not really worth it. Just go the route Sean mentioned

Comment: I don't see any all keyword in the query above.

Comment: @Rishi he said `I tried substituting ALL for IN` == take the query, find IN operator, replace with ALL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be explicit here.

```
WHERE ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check = 'Compliant'
    AND curb_defective_check = 'Compliant'
    AND sidewalk_defective_check = 'Compliant'
    AND ponding_check = 'Compliant'
    etc...
```

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to be; plenty of cute ways to check that all columns contain "Compliant"  but this is the way I'd go for :)

Comment: @CaiusJard sure there are some oddball ways to deal with this but...

Comment: ahh okay this is the most normal way to go about it -- i thought there would a shortcut way using a keyword or something. anyways thanks

Comment: @ziggy There (probably) is; see the last suggestion in my first answer

Answer (score 1):

Here a "oddball" approach just for fun

```
Where concat(
             ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
             curb_defective_check,
             sidewalk_defective_check,
             ponding_check,
             crosswalk_location_check,
             gutter_slope_check,
             flare_slope_check,
             ramp_cross_slope_check,
             ramp_width_check,
             obstacles_check,
             dws_check,
             ramp_running_slope_check,
             apex_turning_space_check,
             cut_through_check,
             landing_length_check,
             landing_width_check,
             landing_slope_check,
             landing_check
            ) = replicate('Compliant',18)
```

Comment: With a footnote of course that calling a function on every row of a table is generally something to avoid; kills performance for all sorts of reasons

Comment: @CaiusJard The replicate is resolved once.  18 ANDs vs 1 concat ... I suspect a nominal impact.

Comment: However you cut it, calling functions on columns generally precludes the use of indexes. In general terms, it should be avoided in a where clause

Comment: @CaiusJard You're assuming these 18 columns are indexed?  I'm not.

Comment: @CaiusJard To be clear, personally, I would opt for the 18 ANDs .. this was just an alternative.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming that anything is indexed in this particular case but as i've mentioned the word **GENERAL** in every single one of the comments i've made, we should **GENERALLY** seek to avoid calling a function on every row. Consider that if even one of these columns were indexed the AND apporach will use the index, the concat approach wont

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way I wouldn't recommend (but see the end of the answer for one that I would):

```
SELECT  curb_reveal_check,
    ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check FROM table    
where REPLACE(CONCAT(ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check), 'Compliant' ,'') = ''
```

Your columns would need to be `'Compliant'` or something else (like 'noncompliant'). If noncompliancy is indicated by blank, it'll fail

You could also:

```
SELECT  curb_reveal_check,
    ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check FROM table    
where CONCAT(ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check)
      = 'CompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliantCompliant'
```

I would still recommend Sean's route in preference to either of these; calling functions on every row in a table is not cool.

## All that said

..if you have a value of 'NonCompliant' or similar you could invert the logic:

```
SELECT  curb_reveal_check,
    ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check FROM table    
where 'NonCompliant' NOT IN (ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
    curb_defective_check,
    sidewalk_defective_check,
    ponding_check,
    crosswalk_location_check,
    gutter_slope_check,
    flare_slope_check,
    ramp_cross_slope_check,
    ramp_width_check,
    obstacles_check,
    dws_check,
    ramp_running_slope_check,
    apex_turning_space_check,
    cut_through_check,
    landing_length_check,
    landing_width_check,
    landing_slope_check,
    landing_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

As another curio, you could UNPIVOT and look for rows that have a compliancy count of 18:

```
WITH unpiv as
SELECT SOME_ID_COLUMN, CheckType, Compliancy  
FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        SOME_ID_COLUMN, 
        curb_reveal_check,
        ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
        curb_defective_check,
        sidewalk_defective_check,
        ponding_check,
        crosswalk_location_check,
        gutter_slope_check,
        flare_slope_check,
        ramp_cross_slope_check,
        ramp_width_check,
        obstacles_check,
        dws_check,
        ramp_running_slope_check,
        apex_turning_space_check,
        cut_through_check,
        landing_length_check,
        landing_width_check,
        landing_slope_check,
        landing_check   
    FROM table
) p  
UNPIVOT  
   (Compliancy FOR CheckType IN   
      (
        curb_reveal_check,
        ramp_running_slope_counter_slope_check,
        curb_defective_check,
        sidewalk_defective_check,
        ponding_check,
        crosswalk_location_check,
        gutter_slope_check,
        flare_slope_check,
        ramp_cross_slope_check,
        ramp_width_check,
        obstacles_check,
        dws_check,
        ramp_running_slope_check,
        apex_turning_space_check,
        cut_through_check,
        landing_length_check,
        landing_width_check,
        landing_slope_check,
        landing_check
    )  
)AS unpvt

SELECT SOME_ID_COLUMN 
FROM unpiv
WHERE compliancy = 'Compliant'
GROUP BY SOME_ID_COLUMN
HAVING COUNT(*) = 18
```

I'd assuming there is some other column that would function as an ID, to actually make it useful...

Answer (score 0):

For a minor variation on Sean's answer, you could use a subquery to make the search string literal (parameter) a little less repeated:

```
SELECT t.stuff
FROM theTable AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'Complaint' AS searchString) AS s 
ON t.field1 = s.searchString
   AND t.field2 = s.searchString
   AND t.field3 = s.searchString
   AND t.field4 = s.searchString
   ...
;
```

Parameterized version:

```
SELECT t.stuff
FROM theTable AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT ? AS searchString) AS s 
ON t.field1 = s.searchString
   AND t.field2 = s.searchString
   AND t.field3 = s.searchString
   AND t.field4 = s.searchString
   ...
;
```